# Mockito inOrder.verify() fails using mock as function argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, verify

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks if methods were invoked in an order. To do that I'm using  Mockito's inOrder.verify() like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldExecuteAllFileCommandsOnAFileInFIFOOrder() {
    // Given
    ProcessFileListCommand command = new ProcessFileListCommand();

    FileCommand fileCommand1 = mock(FileCommand.class, "fileCommand1");
    command.addCommand(fileCommand1);

    FileCommand fileCommand2 = mock(FileCommand.class, "fileCommand2");
    command.addCommand(fileCommand2);

    File file = mock(File.class, "file");
    File[] fileArray = new File[] { file };

    // When
    command.executeOn(fileArray);

    // Then
    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(fileCommand1, fileCommand2);
    inOrder.verify(fileCommand1).executeOn(file);
    inOrder.verify(fileCommand2).executeOn(file);
}
```

However, the second verify() fails with the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.VerificationInOrderFailure: 
Verification in order failure
Wanted but not invoked:
fileCommand2.executeOn(file);
-> at (...)
Wanted anywhere AFTER following interaction:
fileCommand1.executeOn(file);
-> at (...)
```

If I change `.executeOn(file)` to `.executeOn(any(File.class))` the test passes, but I want to make sure that the methods are invoked using the same argument.

Here's the class I'm testing:

```
public class ProcessFileListCommand implements FileListCommand {

    private List<FileCommand> commands = new ArrayList<FileCommand>();

    public void addCommand(final FileCommand command) {
        this.commands.add(command);
    }

    @Override
    public void executeOn(final File[] files) {
        for (File file : files) {
            for (FileCommand command : commands) {
                file = command.executeOn(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test fails because the argument to the second `executeOn()` method call is not the same file as the argument of the first one, since the first file is replaced by another one in

```
 file = command.executeOn(file);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that one :D